# MSSQL Email Reporting Pivot with colors?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, reporting-services

I am trying to pull data and email it so I have a daily update of the latest data. Here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT        MAX(OrderNo) AS INSALESOrderNo, MAX(PostDate) AS INSALESPostDate, NULL AS OEMAINOrderNo, NULL AS OEMAINEntryDate
FROM            INSALES
WHERE        (PostDate =
                             (SELECT        MAX(PostDate) AS Expr1
                               FROM            INSALES AS INSALES_1))
UNION
SELECT        NULL AS Expr1, NULL AS Expr2, MAX(OrderNo) AS Expr3, MAX(EntryDate) AS Expr4
FROM            OEMAIN
WHERE        (EntryDate =
                             (SELECT        MAX(EntryDate) AS Expr1
                               FROM            OEMAIN AS OEMAIN_1))
```

It outputs and looks like this.
[image: SQL Output]

I would rather it look something like this.
[image: New Format]

I really have no idea where to start. I was thinking I could do this in powershell or reporting services. Should I do something with a pivot? I know just enough to get by but this is getting a little too much for me. I have been trying different ways to do it and I just can't seem to figure it out. Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: I think you're mixing up *data* and *formatting*, two very distinct things. What is the intended output format here? Excel workbook? HTML? PDF?

Comment: I would like to to output via email so that I can get a daily status of the data.

Comment: You could do it straight from your database by sending an html-formatted mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply swap around the select:

```
SELECT 'Last Insales Order' AS [Entry], MAX(OrderNo) AS [Order No], MAX(PostDate) AS [Date]
FROM INSALES
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Last Order Added to system', MAX(OrderNo), MAX(EntryDate)
FROM OEMAIN
```

Then take a look at my wiki article on how to email this in a nice HTML table:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17730.sql-server-result-set-in-an-html-email.aspx

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to get it to send as an email with the correct formatting but I still am not sure how I would do the coloring of the cell based on the date. Any ideas?

Comment: For conditional formatting you would need to use SSRS, which involves setting up a reports database on your server and using Visual Studio's Business Intelligence Suite to create a table of results using your query. There are thousands of articles online and then setting up a schedule on the reports dashboard to send it as an email. There's no out-of-the-box method to send this with SQL Server I'm afraid. It's something I've been looking into for over 3 years myself.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will wait on the colors for now as it is not the most important part.

Comment: I was thinking last night, you can use inline CSS styles to color the td and use a case statement in the while loop to set out the logic.

Comment: Ok, I will check that out once I get some more time.